# Ignore xml parse errors in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table that is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ClientId int NOT NULL,
    SentDate datetime NULL,
    ReceivedXML varchar(max) NULL
)
```

The ReceivedXML column should contain something like:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
 <r AddressLine1="123 Main St" AddressLine2="1234" City="Denver" State="CO" />
 <r AddressLine1="234 Main St" AddressLine2="34" City="Denver" State="CO" />
 <r AddressLine1="345 Main St" AddressLine2="23" City="Denver" State="CO" />
</data>"
```

However it is possible that this column can contain invalid xml. I would like to create view that will have Id column that is same as in original table, then it will have AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City and State columns coming from parsed ReceivedXML column (yes, I do realize that I would have multiple rows per Id from original table) and IsValid indicating that I was able to parse XML. Is it possible to have such view that will not blow up when it is unable to parse XML but parse other rows of the original table and set IsValid to false for current row?

Comment: Why not import your data to a staging table first? Then you can insert the data into a new table. You could attempt to parse the xml during the insert. It seems strange to me to have a column named XML but the datatype is varchar(max) because the xml may not actually be valid.

Comment: @SeanLange this is another conversation we have in our team. The problem with that is we have some old code (5+ more years old application) that is using that table and we do not want to update it. Another cons for this solution is that in sql server you can insert into xml column something like 'asdf' without any problems.

Comment: If you truly need to parse these values into real xml then maybe a CLR would be a good way to handle this. Maybe add a column for IsXMLValid as a bit. On new rows this would be NULL. Then your CLR could attempt to parse each value and update the bit column appropriately.

Comment: @SeanLange I ended up adding column IsValid and insert/update trigger that would attempt to parse xml to format we expect and marking record as valid or not. View will ignore all rows that has IsValid flag set to false.

Comment: Just make sure your trigger supports multiple row operations and you should be ok.